# How to link to other songs by the same author?

Tags: songs

I am using the `songs` package to create a little songbook. It works mostly as expected. Amongst other things, I use an author-based index, which lists all pieces by author. In my very minimal example below, Messrs. Bar and Foobar have each contributed one song; Mr. Foo, three.

I was now wondering if there is an easy way to link from each of Mr. Foo’s song entries to the other two (excluding the current one)? The index does this for all songs, of course and I could just use `See also \songlink{song1-3.1}{3}, \songlink{song1-5.1}{5}` at each entry (manually removing the current entry), but this would not be automatic, and difficult to maintain for more complex, real world examples.

Just so you know what I am talking about, my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{songs}
\newauthorindex{artists}{artists}

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{artists}

\beginsong{One}[by={Foo}]
\beginverse*
See also \songlink{song1-3.1}{3}, \songlink{song1-5.1}{5}
One Lorem ipsum.
\endverse
\newpage\endsong

\beginsong{Two}[by={Bar}]
\beginverse*
Two Lorem ipsum.
\endverse
\newpage\endsong

\beginsong{Three}[by={Foo}]
See also \songlink{song1-1.1}{1}, \songlink{song1-5.1}{5}
\beginverse*
Three Lorem ipsum.
\endverse
\newpage\endsong

\beginsong{Four}[by={Foobar}]
\beginverse*
Four Lorem ipsum.
\endverse
\newpage\endsong

\beginsong{Five}[by={Foo}]
See also \songlink{song1-1.1}{1}, \songlink{song1-3.1}{3}
\beginverse*
Five Lorem ipsum.
\endverse
\newpage\endsong

\end{songs}

\showindex{Index by Artist}{artists}

\end{document}
```